# NUnit Tests in generic abstract base class are ignored

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, resharper

I have create a generic abstract base class to do some common tests. The test are showing up, but they are ignored. Why?
Example

```
public abstract class FooBase<TA, TB> : TestBase<TA, TB>
{
   [Test]
   public void SomeBaseTest(){}
}

[TestFixture]
public class ConcreteFooTest:FooBase<IFoo,MyContext>
{
   [Test]
   public void WorkingTest(){}
}
```

It this example are `SomeBaseTest` ignored. 
TestBase are used by all my tests and are only containing some help methods, and no tests

Comment: Do you have any *concrete* non-generic classes derived from this? If not, I'm not sure how you'd expect the tests to be run...

Comment: Of course I have a concrete class that inherits from the abstract base class. I edit my question to show that :-)

Comment: That's odd. I have a similar pattern in my project and it works in Resharper 6.0's runner. I put your code in my project (had to make up `TestBase`) and it doesn't work. I'm trying to sort out the difference. I use generics as well. I have no tests in `FooBase` but I have them in `TestBase`. If I move `SomeBaseTest` to `TestBase` resharper still won't run it. I'll see what I can find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ritch states it is due to RS' test runner. This is a bug in RS 6.0 which is scheduled for fix in 6.1.
See [RSRP-273687 Unit test runner shows inconclusive with test class with generic base class](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273687).

Answer (score 1):

Which test runner are you using?

And have you tried to add the TestFixture attribute?

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class FooBase<TA, TB> : TestBase<TA, TB>
{
    [Test]
    public void SomeBaseTest(){}
}
```

Comment: I'm using Resharper as test runner. 
I have tried both to use and not to use the TestFixture with the same result.

Comment: @magol: Have you tried using the NUnit GUI or console? It's possible that it's a ReSharper issue.

Comment: it works in NUnit GUI, but not in Resharper. Then it is a ReSharper problem :-(

Comment: Yep, had the same problem with Resharper5 test runner.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely with your test runner. Nunit 2.5.10's test runner ran it, Autotest.Net (1.3.1) ran it, and Resharper 6.0's test runner saw it, but wouldn't automatically run it.

Comment: Typically, you're right :-(
 Then I can not use reshape and DotCover as planned

Comment: Well, you could just get rid of the base class. I tend to think that they are a bad idea.

Comment: But how do I test clases that have a base class? I dont want to have the same tests for all clases that inherite the base class.

Comment: @magol - Behavior in your base class probably can be tested once.  After that, only the changes in the derived classes need be tested.

Comment: @magol - Pedro's advice will work if replacing the base class with aggregation (and DI, for testing) doesn't work.